# power bi DAX measure not corresponding against date

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have made a measure as

CALCULATE((COUNT('Raw Data'[Work Item ID])),'Raw Data'[BWV Footage Available] = "No",'Raw Data'[No BWV Reason] <> "No Reason",'Raw Data'[Month Year Complaint closed] <> blank())

But when i put this measure in the values against the date, it shows the same value throughout - it doesn't filter corresponding to the date. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bo7YY.png)

Please help

Comment: Is the date field on the same table? It might be a missing / incorrect relationship

Comment: Yes its on the same table

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the  `Raw Data'[Month Year Complaint closed] <> blank()` part in your CALCULATE function. This 'filter' on the `[Month Year Complaint closed]` column, which returns all rows where this field is not BLANK, overrides the filtering of the same column in your visual (`[Month Year Complaint closed]` on rows). Remove this part from your maesure and filter out the Blank row in your visual.